# Convert vector to map with pointers to members?

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I'm having trouble understanding why the code below

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Student { int id; string name; };

template<typename T, typename U, U T::* Member>
map<U, T> group_by(const vector<T> &items)
{
    map<U, T> result;
    for (vector<T>::const_iterator it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it)
        result[it->*Member] = *it;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Student> items;
    group_by<Student, int, Student::id>(items); //Error
    return 0;
}
```

gives this error:

```
*error C2440*: 'specialization' : cannot convert from `''` to `'int Student::* const '`
```

Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it` is not a pointer to a `Student` so you can't use it with the `->*` member access operator`. I think you meant:

```
result[(*it).*Member] = *it;
```

To form a pointer to member, you need to use `&`, it is not optional. You also need to introduce dependent type names (such as `vector<T>::const_iterator` with `typename`).

This version compiles for me:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Student { int id; string name; };

template<typename T, typename U, U T::* Member>
map<U, T> group_by(const vector<T> &items)
{
    map<U, T> result;
    for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it)
        result[(*it).*Member] = *it;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Student> items;
    group_by<Student, int, &Student::id>(items);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh dang, just a `&` missing. Wow. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the [error should be different](http://ideone.com/62w0B).

`Student::id` cannot appear in a constant expression as a `template` parameter.